# String Arrays: binarySearch to locate whether or not a word is in another Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, spell-checking

In this class it loads my dictionary.txt file, which contains a String array of words that are correctly spelled. Then it uses JFileChooser to allow you to choose a txt file to spellCheck. It searches the dictionary file for each word in your spellCheck file, if it is not found, it is assumed to be spelled wrong and i have to print out the incorrectly spelled word in the console. It is printing out every word of my spellCheck.txt file, instead of those that are spelled incorrectly. I believe it has something to do with my binarySearch method. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class SpellCheck {
    private static String filePath, word;
    private static String[] check, dictionary;
    private static final int GROWTH = 2;
    private static int checkIndex, dictIndex;

    public static void loadDictionary(){
        dictionary = new String[1000];
        File dict = new File("dictionary.txt");
        Scanner dictScanner;
        dictIndex = 0;
        try {
            dictScanner = new Scanner(dict);
            String word = dictScanner.nextLine().trim();
            while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){
                word = dictionary[dictIndex];
                dictIndex++;
                word = dictScanner.nextLine().trim();
                System.out.println(word);
                if(dictIndex >= dictionary.length -1){
                    dictionary = resizeArray(dictionary);
                }

            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readCheckFile(){
        try{
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == 0){
                filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            }else{
                return;
            }
            FileReader spellCheck = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(spellCheck);
            check = new String[1000];
            checkIndex = 0;
            word = "";
            int charAsInt = reader.read();
            while(charAsInt != -1){
                char ch = (char)charAsInt;
                if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){
                    word += ch;
                }else{
                    if(word.length() > 1 && Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(0))){
                        addWordToCheck(word);
                    }
                    word = "";
                }
                charAsInt = reader.read();
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void addWordToCheck(String str) {
        if(checkIndex >= check.length-1){
            resizeArray(check);
        }
        check[checkIndex] = str;
        if(!binarySearch(dictionary, str, 0, dictionary.length-1)){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        checkIndex++;
    }

    public static String[] resizeArray(String[] arr){
        int newLength = arr.length * GROWTH;
        arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newLength);
        return arr;
    }

    private static boolean binarySearch(String[] sortedArray, String target, int start, int end){
        if(start <= end){
            int mid = (start + end)/2;
            if(sortedArray[mid] == null){
                return binarySearch(sortedArray, target, start, mid - 1);
            }
            if(sortedArray[mid].equals(target)){
                return true;
            }
            else if (target.compareTo(sortedArray[mid]) > 0){
                return binarySearch(sortedArray, target, start, mid - 1);
            }
            else{
                return binarySearch(sortedArray, target, mid + 1, end);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the data in your dictionary sorted?

Comment: Yes the dictionary is sorted

Comment: Why don't you use `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch`?

Comment: My professor does not allow us to do that in this project, we must create the method ourselves

Comment: Did you trying debugging it using sysout and checking the console for each Word?

Comment: yes i used sys out and each word from the dictionary.txt file was printing out in sorted order.

Comment: Try to temporarily replace your `binarySearch` with a standard one. So you'll be able to find out if the problem is in `binarySearch` method. When you debug the rest code so there are no more errors left, replace the standard method with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put your dictionary words anywhere. I think

```
word = dictionary[dictIndex];
```

must be

```
dictionary[dictIndex]=word;
```

Comment: that unfortunately did not solve the problem. All of my words from the spellchecker file are still printing out, even when they are spelled right

Comment: This is one of the problems in the code. I can't debug your homework for you David :)

Comment: No worries. Appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First your words are not making it into the `dictionary` array. Check this section of your code:

```
String word = dictScanner.nextLine().trim();
while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){
   word = dictionary[dictIndex]; //replaces word with null
   dictIndex++;
   word = dictScanner.nextLine().trim();
   //...
}
```

A sort of side issue here is that your first `nextLine()` is not safe. So the code probably should look like:

```
String word;
while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){
   word = dictScanner.nextLine().trim(); //sure to have next
   dictionary[dictIndex] = word; //stores word in dictionary
   dictIndex++;
   //...
}
```

The second issue is in your `binarySearch()`, your `compareTo` is going the wrong way. `String.compareTo()` returns a **negative** when the object lexicographically precedes the argument.

Comment: You sir are my savior. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate you taking the time to figure out this problem i couldnt figure out for the longest time.

Comment: @DavidDoll It can be easily avoid if you learn to check [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-).